# GCP App engine app does not see CloudSQL key when deployed but works fine on local

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a Java SpringBoot application deployed on Google Cloud Platform App Engine. The deployment is done from a Github Repository using Cloud Build. The repository file structure is as follows (not all of it but generally)

```
server
   \src\main
            \appengine
               \app.yaml
            \java
            \resources
               \service-account-key.json
   \cloudbuild.yaml
   \pom.xml
client
```

Only server part is deployed and client part is ignored. The application works fine on local development, connects to the CloudSQL and I can modify it too. When I deploy it to App Engine, deployment succeeds but url won't work with the following error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error reading Cloud SQL credentials file: class path resource [service-account-key.json]. Please verify the specified file path.`

This is the related part on my application.properties
`spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=classpath:/service-account-key.json`

I believe the problem might be related to these two so there goes.

app.yaml

```
runtime: java17
instance_class: F1
```

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
  - id: 'Stage app using mvn appengine plugin on mvn cloud build image'
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn'
    dir: 'server'
    args: ['package', 'appengine:stage']
  - id: 'Deploy to app engine using gcloud image'
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    dir: 'server'
    args: ['app', 'deploy', 'target/appengine-staging/app.yaml']
timeout: "1600s"
```

And I don't know how to solve it.
I tried

- deploying manually without Cloud Build
- modifying app.yaml with static url handlers (maybe I got the syntax wrong?)
- putting the key under `server/` instead of `resources/`
- tried using `file:` instead of `classpath:`
- tried specifying the path fully like `src/main/resources/service-account-key.json` and `server/src/main/resources/service-account-key.json`

I can't seem to solve it. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Super easy: don't use a service account key file!!

Seriously, it's a bad practice to use it ([create security hole](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#wlif-key)!), locally, and absolutely useless on Google Cloud. It can help only in rare case.

Use [ADC](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc.)

On Google Cloud you have a metadata server that provide credential info. With App Engine, you can specify [this credential](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/configure-service-accounts#app.yaml). That's the correct way to use service account identity on Google Cloud.

You can use the Google Cloud client libraries, the credential is detected automatically. If you handle the credential object, you can get the default credential like that:

```
GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()
```

Comment: Hey thank you, I tried that and removed the key but I keep getting "[db-instance] The Cloud SQL Instance does not exist or your account is not authorized to access it. Please verify the instance connection name and check the IAM permissions for project " but I am sure the service account I use (default gae service account) has the CloudSQL IAM permissions. What am I missing?